# How to fix custom UITableViewCell dynamic height?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to dynamically calculate the height of the custom UITableViewCell, which looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2mQ8.png "UITableViewCell"
So the text "Hi! Could.." can be any size.

I do this in the following way:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
```

But it doesn't help, it gives me this result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aGsy.jpg

Comment: Most likely your cell's constraints are not configured correctly. You have to make sure the cell's subviews' constraints are configured so their content determines the row height. In your example using 2 labels, the top label needs to be pinned some distance from the top. The second label needs to pinned to the bottom of the first label (as its top constraint.) Its bottom constraint needs to be pinned to the bottom of the cell. Make sure the bottom label does not have a height constraint. But I'm only guessing  - you need to share the cell's constraints for further explanations.

Comment: try to make calculation in UITableViewDelegate's `heightForRowAt IndexPath` function

Answer (score 0):

try giving constraints to all 4 sides of the 'Hi! Could...' UILabel and implement these UITableviewDelegate methods:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
}
```

and make sure you have implemented delegates and datasources correctly.